# Neo4j Degreee of Seperation query efficiency in large DB

Tags: graph, neo4j

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to find the degree of separation between one node to a list of other nodes. For example, I have a node 1, and a list of node (2, 3, 4, 5, ... 15, 16). I want to find the length of the shortest path between 1 and 2, 1 and 3, 1 and 4 and so on. I tried the following cypher query:

cypher 1.7 start s=node(1), d=node(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16) match p=s-[*1..3]-d return d, min(length(p))

on the Movie Rating database (desribed [here](http://markorodriguez.com/2011/09/22/a-graph-based-movie-recommender-engine/), it has 9,962 nodes and 1,012,657 relations).

I've got a outofmemory exception. I tried to limit the list of node to (2, 3) and got the same error.

I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish this type of query more efficiently in a large database. Thanks a bunch for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try ShortestPath instead, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-match.html#match-shortest-path, which might be more effective?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works! Don't see the exception anymore